# Calling member-function of generic member

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I've got a super-class (GraphNode) and sub-class (AStarNode).
Both can be a member by another class thats why I turned the class which uses it into a generic class (GraphEdge).

Inside this class I'd like to call some member-functions of the super-class but the compiler complains that:

```
The method addEdge(GraphEdge<T>) is undefined for the type T
```

How can I fix this or is my approach even ok?

Here's some code that better describes the scenario:

```
public class GraphNode {
   protected Graph graph;

   public GraphEdge addEdge(){
   //some code
   }
}

public class AStarNode extends GraphNode {
   protected GraphEdge predecessor;
}

//The from and to properties can be either AStarNode or GraphNode
public class GraphEdge<T> extends Entity {
   protected T from;
   protected T to;

   public someMethod(){
       from.addEdge(this);
   } 

}
```

Comment: To make sure we're all talking about the same thing, please post a short code snippet that illustrates the relationship between your classes.

Comment: I added some code to describe the scenario.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your GraphEdge class uses a generic type which could be anything, and not just GraphNode. The declaration should be

```
public class GraphEdge<T extends GraphNode> extends Entity {
   protected T from;
   protected T to;
}
```

Additionally, since GraphEdge is a generic type, you should not use it as a raw type in AStarNode:

```
public class AStarNode extends GraphNode {
    protected GraphEdge<PutSomeTypeHere> predecessor;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, only 52 parts to be parameterized but that's fine. How do you think about my approach? Is there a better one available?

Comment: Impossible to say without knowing more about what these classes are for, what they represent and how they are used.

Comment: What if I need Duck Typing and the generics don't inherit a common ancestor? Requiring that would seem to defeat the point of generics