# List of generic object s extending abstract class

Tags: java, generics, javafx, abstract-class

**I have**:

- 1 TableView
- 1 Observable list I use in that TV
- 1 abstract baseclass
  called Media
- 2 subclasses inheriting from Media called Book and CD

**What I want to do**:

Check if the current element in the list is either CD or Book, if so then set its name to the string put into the field fldName.

**Problem**:

```
final ObservableList<Object extends Media> medium = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
```

It says,

- Main.Media is a raw type. References to generic type Main.Media should be parameterized
- Type safety: A generic array of Main.Media> is created for varargs parameter
- Syntax error on token "extends",, expected
- Incorrect number of arguments for type ObserableList; it cannot be parameterized with arguments
- Line breakpoint:Main [line: 35] - start(Stage)

**Code**:

```
final TableView<Object> mediaTable = new TableView<>();
final ObservableList<Object extends Media> medium = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new Book(),
            new CD(),
            new Book(),
            new CD(),
            new Book()
        );


/*Lots of other stuff in between here*/
/*The first if-statememen checks if any field(fldName) is empty*/

else if(medium.get(mediaTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()).getClass()
         .getSimpleName() == "CD" || 
          medium.get(mediaTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex())
         .getClass().getSimpleName() == "Book"){
    String strName = mediaTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()).getName();
                    if(!fldName.getText().isEmpty()){
                        strName = fldName.getText();
                    }
}

/*Lots of other stuff below here*/
```

This one was helpful to some extent but not a full solution:
[Calling member-function of generic member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538774/calling-member-function-of-generic-member)

I think this one might have some kinda solution but I don't understand it:
[Java - Generic List of Generic Abstract Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26840929/java-generic-list-of-generic-abstract-classes)

So how do I solve this?

EDIT: 
The definitions of the classes Media, Book & CD,

```
    public abstract class Media<T>{
    private String author;
    private String name;
    private String genre;
    private String publisher;
    private String mediaType;
    private double price;
    private int year;
    private T length;
    //*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*//
    public String getAuthor(){
        return author;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public String getGenre(){
        return genre;
    }
    public String getPublisher(){
        return publisher;
    }
    public String getMediaType(){
        return mediaType;
    }
    public double getPrice(){
        return price;
    }
    public int getYear(){
        return year;
    }
    public T getLength(){
        return length;
    }
    //*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*//
    public void setAuthor(String author){
        this.author = author;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setGenre(String genre){
        this.genre = genre;
    }
    public void setPublisher(String publisher){
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }
    public void setMediaType(String mediaType){
        this.mediaType = mediaType;
    }
    public void setPrice(double price){
        this.price = price;
    }
    public void setYear(int year){
        this.year = year;
    }
    public void setLength(T length){
        this.length = length;
    }

    public Media(String name, String author, String genre, String publisher, String mediaType, double price, int year){

        setName(name);
        setAuthor(author);
        setGenre(genre);
        setPublisher(publisher);
        setMediaType(mediaType);
        setPrice(price);
        setYear(year);

    }
}

public class Book extends Media<Integer>{
    private String coverType;

    public String getCoverType(){
        return coverType;
    }
    public void setCoverType(String coverType){
        this.coverType = coverType;
    }
    public Book(String name, String author, String genre, String publisher, String mediaType, double price, 
                int year, int length, String coverType){
        super(name, author, genre, publisher, mediaType, price, year);
        setLength(length);
        setCoverType(coverType);
    }
    public Book(){
        super("N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", 0.0, 0);
        setLength(0);
        setCoverType("N/A");
    }
}   

public class CD extends Media<Double>{
    private String type;

    public String getCdType(){
        return type;
    }
    public void setCdType(String type){
        this.type = type;
    }
    public CD(String name, String author, String genre, String publisher, String mediaType, double price, 
                int year, double length, String type){
        super(name, author, genre, publisher, mediaType, price, year);
        setLength(length);
        setCdType(type);
    }
    public CD(){
        super("N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", 0.0, 0);
        setLength(0.0);
        setCdType("N/A");
    }
}
```

EDIT 2:
Changed from "Object extends Media" to "Media" in both TableView and ObservableList, now these errors come up:

- Main.Media is a raw type. Referencs to generic type Main.Media should be parameterized
- Type mismatch: cannot convert from ObservableLIst>> to ObservableList
- Type Safety: A generic array of Main:Media> is created for varargs parameter

**Code**:

```
final TableView<Media> mediaTable = new TableView<>();
final ObservableList<Media> medium = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new Book(),
            new CD(),
            new Book(),
            new CD(),
            new Book()
        );
```

EDIT 3:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    final TableView<Media<T>> mediaTable = new TableView<>();
    final ObservableList<Media<T>> medium = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        new Book(),
        new CD(),
        new Book(),
        new CD(),
        new Book()
    );
```

Comment: Can you include the definitions of the classes `Media`, `CD` and `Book`? Just the definition would probably suffice, no need to include entire class file.

Comment: Ah, too late, I already put it all in, but maybe it'll help too. :)

Comment: Don't use `==` with strings, use `equals()` You are probably looking for "instanceof", see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html

Comment: @RC. Ok, I'm guessing I should use .equals() then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the type parameter to Media like @sillyfly said was correct, but also you have to convert the items inside as well.

So if the previous version looked like this:

```
final TableView<Media> mediaTable = new TableView<>();
final ObservableList<Media> medium = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new Book(),
            new CD(),
            new Book(),
            new CD(),
            new Book()
        );
```

The functioning version will look like this:

```
final TableView<Media<?>> mediaTable = new TableView<>();
final ObservableList<Media<?>> medium = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            (Media<?>)new Book(),
            (Media<?>)new CD(),
            (Media<?>)new Book(),
            (Media<?>)new CD(),
            (Media<?>)new Book()
        );
```

And respectively, had the type parameter been `Media`, then a Book(for instance) would have to be made as `(Media)new Book()`

Answer (score 3):

The reason `ObservableList<Object extends Media>` is a syntax error is that type parameter bounds are only applicable when defining classes or methods, not variables.
More precisely - you can set bounds on a type parameter, not on the type itself:  `class MyClass<T extends OtherClass> {}` is ok, because you apply bounds on the *type parameter* `T`.

When defining a variable you must have the specific type, so in your case you would have `ObservableList<Media>`, as you know all items in the list are `Media` instances (whether they are `Book`s or `CD`s).

Note that in the scope of a generic class or method, the type parameter itself is bound, so you can have something like:

```
class MyClass<T extends OtherClass> {
    // When instantiating a MyClass object, T will be bound, and while you don't know the exact type
    // you can be certain it will be `OtherClass`, or some class that extends it. 
    private List<T> myList;
}
```

So to summarize, both your `TableView` and the `ObservableList` should have `Media` as the type parameter, as this is the most general type you are willing to accept.

As to checking which type each item in the list actually is, as @RC said `instanceof` is a much better (and safer, and probably faster) option than comparing class name:

```
// Since we declared mediaTable as TableView<Media>, getSelectedItem() returns a Media object, which will either be a Book or a CD
Media currentMedia = mediaTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
if (currentMedia instanceof Book) {
    // safe cast because we know currentMedia is indeed an instance of Book
    Book currentBook = (Book)currentMedia;
    ...
} else if (currentMedia instanceof CD) {
    CD currentCD = (CD)currentMedia;
}
```

Comment: I did the instanceof, works great, thank you. :) 
But I tried changing the type to Media in both ObservableList and TableView, and I got some errors, I put them up in the original post at the bottom.

Comment: Could you add the new versions of these lines, or change the original to show how the code currently looks?

Comment: Yes, now I've added the code at the bottom as well. Everything else remains the same(apart from the instanceof, but there's no error there so I didn't include that). The errors show up in the same line, i.e. at medium, the TableView is fine.

Comment: I found that if I remove the type parameter in Book, CD and Media, the error disappears. But the problem is I need to keep them.

Comment: Weird, it works fine for me. Maybe try defining the list and table view as `ObservableList<Media<?>>` and `TableView<Media<?>>` respectively?

Comment: I tried it too but it didn't work either, now I think it might have something to do with the Main-class and the stage-function. I've added the code to it at the bottom. I find that if I add "Media<T>" in TableView and ObservableList, then <T> after stage's parameter list, then the initial error disappears but a new one points to stage.

Comment: Can you put up your code in pastebin or somewhere and send me the link? Maybe then I can figure out why mine doesn't work.